# Check if popup menu become inactive / check if popup menu is visible

Tags: java, android, popupmenu

Hello I am making a small app where i have a list and different popup menus.
I am shading the selected item when the popup menu is triggered. 
Is there a way to check if the popup menu that has been active is now not active any more?
For instance I have the popup menu open and i press somewhere else on the screen. The popup menu Disappears. Is there a listener to capture that?

```
  popupMenu2 = new PopupMenu(getContext(), v);


    popupMenu2.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_unknown_number, 
    popupMenu2.getMenu());

    popupMenu2.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new 
    PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override

    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

          if (item.getItemId() == R.id.delete_unknown) deleteVM(v,model);

                return true;
             }

  });
  popupMenu2.show();
```

Shading is done by

```
 v.setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found he answer. There is a dismiss listener for PopupMenus

```
 popupMenu.setOnDismissListener(new PopupMenu.OnDismissListener(){
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(PopupMenu popupMenu) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }
    });
```